# doc.pull results in "Modifiers and non-modifiers cannot be mixed" only if I'm pulling the last item in the array

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

Here's my document before pulling:

```
{ __v: 23,
  _id: 535cbd5f007976e42b276882,
  iteration: 39,
  name: 'testestset',
  plugin: 'CompetitionBase',
  required_teams: 6,
  maps:
   [ { _map: 535cd556925527502a49fb0f,
       weight: 0,
       _id: 535cd749cc9f34d80fa2f0b6 },
     { _map: 531aaefb44aeed941e5f03bd,
       weight: 1,
       _id: 535cd83925782c881928049f },
     { _map: 535cd558925527502a49fb10,
       weight: 2,
       _id: 535cd83a25782c88192804a0 } ],
  teams: [] }
```

I'm using this code to pull a specific `maps` item:

```
@competition.maps.pull _id : subdoc_id

# Flatten the weights so they always start from 0.
for i, _map of @competition.maps
  @competition.maps[i].weight = i

@competition.save (error, competition) ->
  success_callback competition
```

If I supply an `maps[]._id` other than the last element in the array, then the pull works fine.

However if pull when `subdoc_id == 535cd83a25782c88192804a0` in the above sample, I get the following error when I proceed to `@competition.save()`

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "err": "Modifiers and non-modifiers cannot be mixed",
    "code": 10154,
    "n": 0,
    "connectionId": 148,
    "ok": 1
  }
}
```

If I add further elements to the array, then the _id above would then pull without error.

If I comment out the weight flattening code, then all works fine even removing the last array element, however the part which has me confused is that the only array item removal which has no effect on the weights is the removal of the last item. Removing non-last item triggers a modification of the weights, but that saves successfully.

Answer (score 0):

All of the code here seems to be based around retrieving an item from the data-store and then performing a client side modification, or if otherwise trying to do this server side then the syntax is way off.

Do the operation server side, it is far more efficient:

For absolutely the **last** element in the array use the [**`$pop`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) operator:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("535cbd5f007976e42b276882") },
    { "$pop": { "maps": 1 } }
)
```

Or if you absolutely want an element by `_id` then use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("535cbd5f007976e42b276882") },
    { "$pull": { "maps._id": ObjectId("535cd83a25782c88192804a0") } }
)
```

So this is what MongoDB is really good for. I encourage you to actually use it.